# Field 'caturl' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error message
Field 'caturl' doesn't have a default value

I have tried

```
 ALTER TABLE `category` MODIFY COLUMN `caturl` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}';
```

yes the form does post but I doesnot copy or duplicate the data of 1stcolumn into the `carturl` column/

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['maincat']) & empty($_POST['maincat'])) {
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['name']);
    $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['description']);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO category (name, description) VALUES ('$name', '$description')";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    if ($res) {
        $smsg = "Category Added Succesfully";
    } else {
        $fmsg = "Failed to Add Category";
    }
}
```

I would like the caturl column to have the same data as the name column in the category table.

Comment: Do proper error checking on your queries and use prepared statements instead of concatenation and `mysqli_real_escape_string`!

Comment: If you know what the value should be why is not part of the query?

Comment: Because I would want to add the value by default rather than hav NULL, {} or 0 in the category table.

Comment: That should work fine, so probably your `ALTER` statement isn't being run as expected. Do a `SHOW CREATE TABLE category` in MySQL to be sure.